# how to change the text direction of the error message for the TextFormField to make it right to left

Tags: flutter, text, message

InputDecoration  has the property for changing it's style but can't find anything about it's direction

[text form error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHChp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your TextFormField inside Directionality Widget and set the direction to rtl like this :

```
Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: TextFormField()
     )
```